# Преобразование словаря в матрицу смежности

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно перевести словарь в матрицу смежности

```
graph0 ={'1' : ['2','3','4'],

         '2' : ['1','3','5'],
         '3' : ['1','2','4'],
         '4' : ['1','3','5'],
         '5' : ['2','4'],}

n = 5
adjMatrix = [[0 for i in range(n)] for k in range(n) ]

for i in range(n):
    u = int(graph0[str(i+1)][0])
    v = int(graph0[str(i+1)][1])
    adjMatrix[int(u)-1][int(v)-1]=1
    adjMatrix[int(v)-1][int(u)-1]=1

print(adjMatrix)
```

Выводит матрицу не правильную

Answer (score 1):

```
graph = {
    '1' : [ '2','3','4' ],
    '2' : [ '1','3','5' ],
    '3' : [ '1','2','4' ],
    '4' : [ '1','3','5' ],
    '5' : [ '2','4' ]
}

n = 5

matrix = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]

for vertex_y, value in graph.items():
    for vertex_x in value:
        matrix[int(vertex_y) - 1][int(vertex_x) - 1] = 1

for row in matrix:
    print(row)

# [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
# [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
# [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
# [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
# [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @ДмитрийЮзов не за что. если ответ был полезен, можно отметить его решением